# Phantom Type Error (Python 3.3)

Tags: python, typeerror

I tried to run this code with a dataList being a list of floats:

```
meanData = round(float((sum(dataList) / len(dataList))), 2)
```

It gives me a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str', even though I'm not even using the + operator. What could be the issue?

Comment: "even though I'm not even using the + operator." You don't, but what do you think what `sum()` does?

Answer (score 3):

`dataList` must contain one or more strings.  Furthermore, `sum` does not support strings.

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, '4']
>>> sum(lst)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>>
```

To fix the problem, you need to make `dataList` contain only integers or floats.

Comment: I figured out what was happening. I had a for loop that went through each member in the list, but I forgot float() doesn't work in place. That always seems to trip me up.

Answer (score 2):

`dataList` contains both numbers and strings. Fix that.

Comment: `dataList` needn't contain numbers to produce this message, I don't think, because the default start value is 0.

Comment: @DSM: And even if you fix that by using a custom `start`, like `sum(dataList, '')`, you'll just get `TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]`.